# How to display an array consisting of object with property and value in a data grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datagrid

I have an array consisting of objects. Each object has property and value. The properties are latitude,longitude and name. I need to display this array in a data grid view. Below is my array,

[image]

Could any one share examples or any suggestions

Thanks!

Comment: which datagrid plugin you are using is it jqGrid or datatables or other else?

Comment: Im trying to use juqery grid. Are there any other ways?

Comment: I am suggesting to use https://datatables.net/, because lots of helps available.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```js
$(function(){
var data = [{
  "Latitude": 18.00,
  "Longitude": 23.00,
  "Name": "Pune"
}, {
  "Latitude": 14.00,
  "Longitude": 24.00,
  "Name": "Mumbai"
}, {
  "Latitude": 34.00,
  "Longitude": -4.00,
  "Name": "Delhi"
},{
  "Latitude": 23.00,
  "Longitude": 23.00,
  "Name": "Jaipur"
}];
$.each(data,function(index,value) {

      row="<tr><td>"+value.Latitude+"</td><td>"+value.Longitude+"</td><td>"+value.Name+"</td><tr>";
  
  $("#grid").append(row);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Latitude
    </th>
    <th>
      Longitude
    </th>
    <th>
      Place
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With dynamic header

But it will only work if all your object have same properties

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "Latitude": 18.00,
    "Longitude": 23.00,
    "Name": "Pune"
  }, {
    "Latitude": 14.00,
    "Longitude": 24.00,
    "Name": "Mumbai"
  }, {
    "Latitude": 34.00,
    "Longitude": -4.00,
    "Name": "Delhi"
  }, {
    "Latitude": 23.00,
    "Longitude": 23.00,
    "Name": "Jaipur"
  }];
  header = "<tr>"
  $.each(data[0], function(prop, value) {
    header += "<th>" + prop + "</th>";
  });
  header += "</tr>"
  $("#grid").append(header);

  $.each(data, function(index, obj) {

    row = "<tr>";
    $.each(obj, function(prop, value) {
      row += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
    });
    row += "</tr>";

    $("#grid").append(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to have a dynamic table header without hardcoding the header names?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dataTables jquery plugin](https://datatables.net/) in easy way and very big documentation and community available for customizing datatables help.

```js
var dataSet = [{
  "Latitude": 18.00,
  "Longitude": 23.00,
  "Name": "Pune"
}, {
  "Latitude": 14.00,
  "Longitude": 24.00,
  "Name": "Mumbai"
}, {
  "Latitude": 34.004654,
  "Longitude": -4.005465,
  "Name": "Delhi"
},{
  "Latitude": 23.004564,
  "Longitude": 23.007897,
  "Name": "Jaipur"
}];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name" ,"title":"Custom Name"},
            { "data": "Latitude" },
            { "data": "Longitude" },
            
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
@import "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Latitude</th>
                <th>Longitude</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to have a dynamic table header without hardcoding the header names?

Comment: I have modified for get dynamic name of column name

Comment: If you like my answer, please mark as correct and up vote it. :)

Comment: Sure I will. Could you let me know where have you modified to get dynamic column  names?

Comment: You are hardcoding it in the HTML. It should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

as jquery is specify in your tags question, lot of jquery plugins allow to generate datagrid. The jquery official website is a good bet to start digging the web:

https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/datagrid/